# How to inherit from a CSLA object in F#?

Tags: f#, csla

I would like to get the benefits of CSLA from F#, but I am having trouble with inheritance. Here is the ProjectTracker ResourceInfo class. Can someone please show how to do it in F#?

```
using Csla;
using System;
using Csla.Serialization;

namespace ProjectTracker.Library
{
  [Serializable()]
  public class ResourceInfo : ReadOnlyBase<ResourceInfo>
  {
    private static PropertyInfo<int> IdProperty = RegisterProperty<int>(c => c.Id);
    public int Id
    {
      get { return GetProperty(IdProperty); }
      private set { LoadProperty(IdProperty, value); }
    }

    private static PropertyInfo<string> NameProperty = RegisterProperty<string>(c => c.Name);
    public string Name
    {
      get { return GetProperty(NameProperty); }
      private set { LoadProperty(NameProperty, value); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return Name;
    }

    internal ResourceInfo(int id, string lastname, string firstname)
    {
      Id = id;
      Name = string.Format("{0}, {1}", lastname, firstname);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution by jpalmer shows the general structure, but I think there are a couple of problems. I don't have experience with CSLA, so I haven't tried running this, but I downloaded the DLL and tried type-checking the sample.

First of all, the `RegisterProperty` method does not take a lambda function, but an expression (and uses it to get information about the property using reflection). To get this working, you need to write a helper using F# quotations:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open System.Linq.Expressions

let prop (q:Expr<'T -> 'R>) = 
  match q with
  | Patterns.Lambda(v, Patterns.PropertyGet(_, pi, _)) -> 
      let v = Expression.Variable(v.Type)
      Expression.Lambda<Func<'T, 'R>>
        (Expression.Property(v, pi), [v])
  | _ -> failwith "wrong quotation"
```

This turns a quoted F# lambda function to a C# expression tree in the expected format. You can then call `RegisterProperty` with something like `prop <@ fun (a:Foo) -> a.Bar @>` as an argument.

I also see that `IdProperty` should be static, which can be done using `static let` (if it is private). The following should be the right way of defining type with one property:

```
[<Serializable>]
type ResourceInfo internal (id:int, lastname:string, firstname:string) as this =
  inherit ReadOnlyBase<ResourceInfo>()

  // Code executed as part of the constructor    
  do this.Id <- id

  static let IdProperty = 
    ReadOnlyBase<ResourceInfo>.RegisterProperty<int>
      (prop <@ fun (r:ResourceInfo) -> r.Id @>)

  member x.Id 
    with get() = x.GetProperty(IdProperty) |> unbox
    and set(v) = x.LoadProperty(IdProperty, v)
```

I generally quite like the style when you write accessibility modifiers directly in your code (as in C#), so I annotated the constructor with `internal` as in your code. I also added constructor body that sets the `Id` property when the object is created.

Answer (score 0):

This should be close - the standard way to do the access control in F# is to use signature files, which I left out

```
module ProjectTracker.Library
open Csla;
open System;
open Csla.Serialization;

  [<Serializable>]
  type  ResourceInfo(id, lastname, firstname) =
    inherit ReadOnlyBase<ResourceInfo>()
    Id <- id
    Name <- sprintf "%s, %s" lastname firstname
    let IdProperty = RegisterProperty<int>(fun c -> c.Id); 
    member x.Id with get() = GetProperty(IdProperty) and set(v) = LoadProperty(IdProperty, v)

   //skipped a property here - similar to above
    override x.ToString() = Name
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tomas
I am honored by your reply and touched by your effort to do so--downloading CSLA, identifying the expression as a problem, and creating a non-obvious way to deal with it. I love your book, [Real-World Functional Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988924), which goes beyond language features and into how to apply them to important real-world problems.

CSLA was out before C# had lambdas, so I went back to see how Lhotka then used RegisterProperty. If other users want to avoid expressions, it looks like this works, too:

```
static let IdProperty =
  ReadOnlyBase<ResourceInfo>.RegisterProperty
    (typeof<ResourceInfo>, new PropertyInfo<int>("Id"))
```